# Using Backbone.js - Removing jQuery

Tags: backbone.js

I wanted to see what I would need to do to use Backbone BUT not use jQuery?

I want to use Famo.us for the views and so trying to decouple jQuery from Backbone.  I will mostly be using just the Backbone Models and Collections - though may use the framework for a View and insert 'Famo.us' code. Bit Famo.us has this integration low on the list of things to do...

If I just wanted to use the Models and Collections of Backbone, what would I need to do in order for it to run successfully without jQuery?

Thanks.

-- I've just tried replacing jQuery with jBone but it doesn't seem to like the change:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  nodeRequire: require,
  paths: {
    "backbone" : "vendor/backbone.min",
//    exoskeleton : "vendor/exoskeleton.min",
    jbone: "vendor/jbone.min",
    json2: "vendor/json2",
    "requirejs": "vendor/requirejs/require",
    underscore: "vendor/underscore.min"
  },
  shim: {
    jbone: {
      exports: "$"
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ["jbone", "underscore", "json2"],
      exports: "Backbone"
    }
  }
//  map: {
//    'exoskeleton': {'underscore': 'underscore-empty'}, // Remap Exoskeleton to use an empty underscore file.
//    '*': {
//      'underscore': 'underscore-private',  // Everything else in the app that requests _ will use the Backbone.utils version.
//      'backbone': 'exoskeleton'
//    }
//  }
});
```

I did try Exoskeleton though could not see examples of how to use it properly - so I wanted to try and simply remove jQuery and try jBone.

I'm going to be using Famo.us for the Views, so only really need to use Backbone for the MC part of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone use jQuery only to manipulate with DOM. If you won't do that - you didn't need jQuery ( for example you are using only model system with enother framework or work at server side).

You also can use another lib instead of jQuery ( with the same API ) - like Eksoskeleton or other likes - - just redefine Backbone.$

P.s  look at https://github.com/inkling/backbone.native and https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Using-Backbone-without-jQuery

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate all that and have read the link you have mentioned, and looking into Exoskeleton.  Backbone.Native doesn't give examples of how to load the library in preference to jQuery when you are using RequireJS.

Comment: If you want to use ReactJS - you should use only Events/Models/Collections

Comment: Or you can use Backbone.Views and redefine all methods to apply ReactOS views methods instead of standart DOM work. What is your goal?

Comment: Did you try the easiest hack in config - define jquery with path to jbone?

Comment: I've managed to use Exoskeleton and managing to get a collection return - thanks for everyone suggesting things